# How do I set a redirect to custom 403 and 404 pages?

Tags: 8

What I am trying to do is redirecting users to a custom page, instead of showing the standard error message, when a 403 or 404 error happens.

I tried to use /error/404 on the *Base site settings* page and create a node with that path alias, but it didn’t work. When I try to access some random URL, it still shows a standard error message, not the /error/404 node.

Did I misunderstand how the feature work? Should I try another approach?

Comment: You need to specify the node path that will be displayed as error page. It's difficult to tell do you just want to display custom content on 403/404 or do you really want to redirect and if so, why? Then maybe just have a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login and how they did it.

Comment: what error message does it show?

Comment: You don't need an alias, because the custom 403/404 page won't be a redirect. It will be displayed under the same URL which caused the 403/404. So simply configure an existing node and it should work: /node/123

Comment: @sonfd It shows just "The requested page could not be found" when I enter some random incorrect url.

Comment: @leymannx Thank you for the advice. I want to display custom content when 403 or 404 error occurs. I don't need redirect.

Comment: @4k4 Thank you. I tried as you offered but it didn't work. I will investigate and try to find a reason of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is build in to Drupal and the simple way to do this is to create separate pages for both error codes and add your own wording as necessary.

Then go to the error pages section of site settings at /admin/config/system/site-information and add the path of your custom error pages.

Comment: OP is telling they did exactly that and it didn't work.